# Why does a relative positioned element appear above a floated element?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have two elements: one with relative positioning that defines most of my header, and a smaller one that I'd like to "float" on top of it.

```
<div id=floater style="float:right">
Floater!
</div>
<div id=header style="width: 100%; position: relative; background-color: lightgreen">
This is the header
</div>
```

As shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfengel/eax6wdpx/2/), the floated component is invisible. But if you remove the `position: relative`, the floated element pops right up. Futzing with the z-index hasn't yielded anything of interest.

The header component isn't "mine"; it's inherited through React-Bootstrap. I could override, but right now I'm mostly looking to understand the interaction of float and relative positioning.

Comment: This behavior seems pretty normal to me. Keep in mind that `z-index` has no effect on statically positioned elements. What's your goal again?

Comment: behavior is correct position:relative brings up front element https://jsfiddle.net/eax6wdpx/3/ , you also  need to clear or modify the BFC https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context if you want to move element away from floats. -  2 of many ways to do so: https://jsfiddle.net/eax6wdpx/4/ https://jsfiddle.net/eax6wdpx/5/

Comment: I did figure out what I should have been doing: I used absolute positioning instead of the float, which is probably right-enough for this application. 

In the process I discovered that even a non-floated element will appear below the relative position one, which seems to be the clue: relative positioned elements seem to go on top.

Comment: Re "Futzing with the z-index":  If you add `position: relative` to the floater, it **will** appear on top:  https://jsfiddle.net/ouL8tp5v/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements without a position property set will default to "position:static" which ignores all positioning properties such as z-index. By setting relative positioning to the header element you have introduced the z-index positioning property to that element bringing it in front of the floater element which does not have a z-index property.

Since z-index will be ignored with a static floater element you will have to give that element a position property (absolute, relative or fixed) so it can have z-index as well.

For your example "position: relative;" would work. Once you have set the position property on the floater element you would need to add a z-index value to it that's higher then the header element. Which in this case z-index:1 would be a higher value since z-index is set to default.

**Example:**

```
<div id=floater style="float:right; position: relative; z-index: 1;">
   Floater!
</div>
<div id=header style="width: 100%; position: relative; background-color:   lightgreen">
  This is the header
</div>
```

Comment: The idea that I could float AND use position is kind of an eye-opener, but yeah, I get it. Thanks.

Comment: Its not necessarily good practice, however, relative positioning & floats work friendly with each if used correctly. Relative position means relative to itself wherever it may be on the page. A better alternative in this case would be to trash the float and just use relative positioning by itself instead.

Answer (score 1):

When elements are positioned, they can overlap other elements. If two positioned elements overlap without a z-index specified, the element positioned last in the HTML code will be shown on top.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function of the [painting order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/zindex.html#painting-order)

In-flow, non-positioned, block-level elements are painted in step 4

Floated items are painted at step 5. So the floated element is painted "on top" of the static div and you see it displayed.

But positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto' or 'z-index: 0' are painted in step 8. So adding `position:relative` to the div means that it is now painted "on top" of the floated element, hiding it.